# Solve Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of equations I'm trying to solve:

$$\begin{align}Q &= MP \\
Q^\prime &= M\Pi P\end{align}$$

$Q$, $Q^\prime$, and $P$ are all $4\times n$ matrices, and $M$ and $\Pi$ are both $4\times4$ matrices. Unfortunately, $M$ is not invertible because it has a zero determinant, and neither are $Q$, $Q^\prime$, or $P$ because they are not square. $\Pi$ should be invertible.

Given that I know $Q$, $Q^\prime$, and $M$, how can I find $\Pi$ and $P$?

Note the problem is over determined, so I'm looking for a least squares type solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$M^+$ denote the Moore-Penrose psuedoinverse of $M$

Solving $MP=Q$ gives:

$P=M^+Q$

Then to find $\Pi$ we can left multiply by $M^+$ and right multiply by $Q^+M=P^+$

$\Pi=M^+Q'Q^+M+(I-M^+M)X + Y(I-M^+QQ^+M)$

For arbitrary $4\times4$ matrices $X,Y$

The extra terms add a matrix whose columns are in the nullspace of $M$ and one who's rows are in the left nullspace of $P$. It represents our freedom in choosing $\Pi$

**Note:** This will be the least squares solution relative to the vectorized version of the system.

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: how do I solve for pi? it's also unknown. How do I calculate the Moore-Penrose psuedo-inverse?

Comment: I think I can figure out my second question (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Construction), but how do I solve for PI?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought $\Pi$ was also known.

Comment: @Jason I edited the question. Are you familiar with the Singular Value Decomposition? That is usually the first step. The requirement that $\Pi$ is invertible is not exactly satisfied by this solution, but we can always find a matrix that is arbitrarily close to it which is invertible.

Comment: @Jason I need to make another change.

Comment: @Jason okay, it now specifies what choices we can try for $\Pi$ in search of one that is both invertible AND a least squares solution.

Comment: If I need to clarify anything, let me know. I am not sure this is extremely easy to follow.

Comment: This is great. How do I choose X and Y?

Comment: @Jason On that point I am not exactly sure. You can choose them arbitrarily and still have a least-squares solution, but $\Pi$ will only be invertible for some (or maybe none) choices. I am not sure of a general condition for when det(A+BX+YC)!=0

Comment: The dimension is relatively small though once you get to this point (And it no longer depends on n). A solver in matlab or mathematica might be able to handle it.